# App opened by google play

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

Is there an intent being sent by google market, when the user first opens the app ?

I want to catch the event that the user clicks on a facebook request, and goes to the google play market to install my app

the part of user clicking on facebook request to go to google play market i already have.

But I want to process this request once the user opens the app for the first time.

How do i know that this exact situation has happened?

Comment: Have you tried setting a value on the preferences on first run, and then checking it every run? if so, why wouldn't this work for you?

Comment: because the request itself had some data in it, and i wanted to pass that to the app

Answer (score 0):

No there is no intent being sent by Google Play when the app is opened for 1st time. When the app is installed on phone an intent is sent by google play which can be received by other apps installed on the device. Even this intent is not received by the app which is installed.

As Merlevede suggested, the best way to deal with this is by setting a shared preference, when the app is launched for the first time.

It can be done in following way :

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences;
boolean isAppLaunched = false;
appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isAppLaunched = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppLaunched", false);

if(!isAppLaunched) {

//Do your stuff


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isAppLaunched", true);
editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: That's not what i intended to do. I have this preference anyway. My Problem is, when user installed my app by clicking a facebook request, that had some data in it, that i wanted to pass to the app. Is this data lost?

Comment: @LenaBru Why don't you use facebook API on your app? You detect the users facebook account, send it to your server, and try to make a match with the facebook account that clicked on the link.

Comment: the user that opened my app for the first time -> may not have logged in using facebook